# How to restrict remote user to connect SQL Server Database except some of them using Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10?

Tags: sql-server, block, kaspersky

I don't want anyone to connect SQL Server from another domain except some of them.

I tried to block the port of SQL server through Kaspersky on my database server. But it doesn't block

[image: Kaspersky block port]

Comment: Why you don't use SQL Server integrated security? How other domain users are connecting actually?

Comment: @serge for every one hour the data will move to another sql server(which is in another domain).. so except that ip I want to block rest of them

Comment: So you have several SQL Servers. How other domain users are connecting to these SQL Servers actually?

Comment: @serge using crystal report xi application. they are running the report from another domain.

Comment: I mean how users are authenticated by SQL Server?

Comment: @serge i created one common sql server integrated security to run report for users. that authentication without password to run report only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182497/discussion-between-liam-neesan-and-serge).